# Using Xamarin.Android and Media Service in Azure for live broadcasting

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am looking for integrating Media Service from azure to Xamarin Android for live broadcasting and viewing the live with on demand videos. For example I need to implement the live video broadcasting like a Facebook app using Azure Media Services and also view the live and archived videos from blob storage. I am unable to get the resource to implement that from official documents of Azure and Xamarin and through the Xamarin University.

So I am here to learn this which will be useful to almost every one willing to implement this kind of features in feature.

There is a official video showing the upload of a video recorded using xamarin application to Azure Media Service and viewing back on the Xamarin app the link is as follows, but there is no approach for making a live broadcasting possible through the same.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/media-streaming-apps-with-azure-and-xamarin/

Xamarin.Android is not compulsory like it may be from Xamarin Forms also the thing is like we just need the android part, I will be happily looking forward to take any kind of help you can offer to get this working.

Scope of App Requirement/Workflow::

1)  App should be able to broad cast live (like going live on Facebook application)

2)  That should be capable to view the live broadcasts (like we can stream the live content in Facebook application)

3)  That should be able to view the archived videos in blob storage (I know how to access the blob storage and download the video to view it on mobile but I don’t know the process to stream the video while it is being downloaded in the background like it does in Youtube or Facebook application).

Answer (score 0):

> Using Xamarin.Android and Media Service in Azure for live broadcasting

You could refer to the [xamarin-azure-businessreview sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/xamarin-azure-businessreview).

> Demo app showing how to use several Azure services with Xamarin including Azure AD B2C, Azure Cosmos DB, Azure Functions, Azure App Services, and Azure Media Services